# Adding an array to a hashtable

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, hashtable

I have an array full of values, myArray[]

I'm trying place this array in a hash table to pass over the socket from my node.js server.

I want the array in the hash table to contain all the same information as myArray.

```
var item = [
    {    hashArray: []     }
];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    item.hashArray.push(myArray[i]);
}
```

I receive the error that I can't call push of undefined.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Thanks very much everyone, I see what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating `item` as an array with an object on the zero'th index:

```
var item = [
    {    hashArray: []     }
];
```

Either let `item` be the object:

```
var item = {
    hashArray: []
};
```

I assume this to be what you want, unless `item` is *meant* to be an array, in which case you should `push()` to `item[0]`:

```
item[0].hashArray.push(myArray[i]);
```

---

**EDIT**
On a side-note, why not just let the `hashArray` array hold the values from `myArray`?

```
var item = {
    hashArray: myArray
};
```

(Asking out of curiosity here :) )

Comment: Well now that I have it working correctly I'm actually just going to push the values that were going into myArray straight into hashArray. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you wraped the object containing `hashArray` in an array. To access the field `hashArray` you have to do the following:

```
item[0].hashArray.push(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item[0].hashArray.push(myArray[i]);
```

or

```
var item = {    hashArray: []     };
```